# Why don't have a match while comparing two strings - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an array that holds list of strings

```
$result.packagename holds a list of names like 
PublisherServiceOnIDU
LogicalShadowDatabase 
ManagementConsoleClient 
ProbeDatabase 
FilewalkProbeWithoutProbeSvc
ADWalkProbeWithoutProbeSvc
```

I want to find a match between a file name to one of the names above

```
This is the file name:
$temp = "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\42c950490f3f4643b2432b09b29cf4b7\638133824672932949\ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120\google.O365.SDK.dll"
```

I will take only the ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120 part by:

```
$parentname = $temp.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[-2]
```

Now I run in a loop in order to find a match

```
foreach ($res in $result) {
    $pack_name = $res.PackageName
        if ($parentname -match $pack_name) {
            Write-host "Match"
        }
    }
```

I even tried with $pack_name* and also with -like (I preferred the -match)
If I define the variables like this its working:

```
$parentname = "ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120"
foreach ($res in $result) {
    $pack_name = "ManagementConsoleClient"
        if ($parentname -match $pack_name) {
            Write-host "Match"
        }
    }
```

Second issue with a name of file called:

```
$dll.name = Google.O365.SDK.dll
```

Trying to match with:

```
$dll_name = ${TargetRootFolder}Google.O365.SDK.dll
```

($dll.name -match $dll_name)

Why there is no match?

Comment: Try trimming any excess white space, that might be the reason `$pack_name.Trim()`

Comment: You right this was the problem

Comment: Is `$result` an array, or is it an object and `$result.packagename` is the array? Do you need to do `foreach($pack_name in $result.packagename){if($parentname -match $pack_name){write-host "Match"}}` to iterate that?

Comment: Try adding in for loop 1) $pack_name | Format-Table 2) $parentname | Format-Table

Comment: I still dont know why the space at the end lead to not match.

Comment: well a space is a character which doesnt lead to a match, `'a' -match ' a '` is false

Comment: Now I have a new issue. -match is not working if the name is: Google.O365.SDK.dll comparing with ${TargetRootFolder}Google.O365.SDK.dll what could be the problem now?
($dll.name -match $dll_name)

Comment: The `-match` parameter uses "RegEx" for pattern matching, the period is part of the special characters on it.

Comment: So how it works for ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120 ?
Also have period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-match` matches a regex pattern defined on the Right-Hand-Side to whatever string is given on the Left-Hand-Side, not the other way around.

So if you match

```
$path = "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\42c950490f3f4643b2432b09b29cf4b7\638133824672932949\ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120\google.O365.SDK.dll"
$path -match 'google.O365.SDK.dll'
```

the result is `True`

If however you try to match

```
$path = "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\42c950490f3f4643b2432b09b29cf4b7\638133824672932949\ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120\google.O365.SDK.dll"
'google.O365.SDK.dll' -match [regex]::Escape($path)
```

the result will be `False`

<sup>The long `$path` can never be part of the shorter 'google.O365.SDK.dll' string on the left</sup>

Because the strings you use in the pattern to match contain characters with special meaning in regex (see table below),
you should escape these characters with a backslash.
The most convenient way of doing that is by using the `[regex]::Escape()` static method.

The reason the first (non-escaped) code works anyway is that the path to match against does not contain anything like 'google**X**o365**Y**sdk**Z**dll', so in that particular case it doesn't matter if the dot is matched against **any** character.

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

---

As per your comment:

Your code to match the ManagementConsoleClient part of the path to an array of package names, assuming your variable `$result` is either a Hashtable with a key 'PackageName' or an object with property 'PackageName' that stores this array,
you need to set the foreach loop to run over the arrays elements instead of looping over the object or Hashtable itself like you do with `foreach ($res in $result)`

Also `$pack_name = $res.PackageName` will then contain the entire array of strings and matching "ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120" against an array will fail.

Try

```
$parentname = "ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120"
foreach ($pack_name in $result.PackageName.Trim()) { 
    # if there can be regex special characters here, use [regex]::Escape($pack_name) 
    if ($parentname -match $pack_name) {
        Write-host "Match" 
    }
}
```

Comment: But this also has special character like dot ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120 I don’t understand maybe because the left side doesn’t contain  dot?

Comment: There is no problem to match google.O365.SDK.dll against google.O365.SDK.dll right? Regarding to your answer like can be used right?

Comment: @Bandit No, no problem as long as you are aware that a pattern `google.O365.SDK.dll` **without** escaping the dots would also match `googleXo365YsdkZdll`, because the dot matches any character among which.. also the dot.

Comment: can you look at my question regarding ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120 please?

Comment: @bandit please than first explain what variable `$result` is. Is that a Hashtable where uner key `packagename` there is an array of package names without the version, or ?? Do the elements in that array need to be trimmed of whitespace characters perhaps?

Comment: I am asking a very simple question. Why there is a match between ManagementConsoleClient with ManagementConsoleClient_4.0.0.120 , this is because there are no special characters in the left side?

Comment: I am not using Hash and $pack_name = $res.PackageName not contain the entire array of strings, only a one string and after the trim() its working well. what I am asking is why its working, because the left side does not include a special characters?

Comment: @Bandit The special characters are only of concern in the pattern on the Right-Hand-Side of `-match`. Whatever's on the left is just the plain string you are matching the pattern against to find out if that pattern is part of or equal to the plain-text string on the left